# TCL :I am getting the following error while creating fibonacci

Tags: list, tcl

```
proc Fibonacci {x} {
    set n(0) 0; set n(1) 1
    set i 2
    while {$i <= $x} {
        set n($i) [expr n($i-2) + n($i-1)]
        incr i
    }
    return $n($i)
}
set y [Fibonacci 10]
puts "$y"
```

I am getting the below error while compliling the above program. please correct me

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: Some other ways to implement the fibonacci sequence [here](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Fibonacci_sequence#Tcl)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem is twofold in this statement:

```
set n($i) [expr n($i-2) + n($i-1)]
```

First of all, you have to get the value of `n($i-2)`, not it's name, so you should change it to this:

```
set n($i) [expr {$n($i-2) + $n($i-1)}]
```

I also introduced `{}` to make `expr` a bit tidier and less error-prone. However, that still won't work, because `$i-2` will not be calculated before trying to index the `n` array, so you need this:

```
set n($i) [expr {$n([expr {$i-2}]) + $n([expr {$i-1}])}]
```

Fixed? Nope, this line is still wrong:

```
return $n($i)
```

You see, you index by `$i`, but in your loop, you write to `n($i)` and after that immediately increase `i`, so it will be one higher than the last element. You need to change it to this:

```
return $n($x)
```

This gives a working version with your code:

```
proc Fibonacci {x} {
    set n(0) 0
    set n(1) 1
    set i 2
    while {$i <= $x} {
        set n($i) [expr {$n([expr {$i-2}]) + $n([expr {$i-1}])}]
        incr i
    }
    return $n($x)
}
set y [Fibonacci 10]
puts "$y"
```

This can still be done bether however, let's use `for` instead of while:

```
proc Fibonacci1 {x} {
    set n(0) 0
    set n(1) 1
    for {set i 2} {$i <= $x} {incr i} {
        set n($i) [expr {$n([expr {$i-2}]) + $n([expr {$i-1}])}]
    }
    return $n($x)
}
```

And let's replace that array by a list, which semantics work much better here:

```
proc Fibonacci2 {x} {
    set n [list 0 1]
    for {set i 2} {$i <= $x} {incr i} {
        lappend n [expr {[lindex $n end] + [lindex $n end-1]}]
    }
    return [lindex $n end]
}
```

Arrays are quite useless here as they are actually associative containers in tcl, a list is a sequential container, what you obviously use in this algorithm. You can see this in speed, this was what I got on my computer with tcl 8.6:

```
time {Fibonacci1 100} 10000
64.1805 microseconds per iteration
time {Fibonacci2 100} 10000
23.9295 microseconds per iteration
```

Comment: I think you'll find this faster, much much faster: `proc Fibonacci3 n {set a 0;set b 1;for {set i 2} {$i<=$n} {incr i} {set b [expr {$a + [set a $b]}]};return $b}` (Getting faster than that requires real math tricks…)

Comment: @donal true, but that is a different algorithm, I just optimized his to improve readability and point out the difference between array and list.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a working solution based on your code:

```
proc Fibonacci {x} {
    set n(0) 0; set n(1) 1
    set i 2 
    while {$i <= $x} {
        set fiboMinus1 $n([expr {$i - 1}])
        set fiboMinus2 $n([expr {$i - 2}])
        set n($i) [expr {$fiboMinus1 + $fiboMinus2}]
        incr i
    }   
    return $n($x)
}   

set y [Fibonacci 10] 
puts "$y"
```

Comment: Oops. I forgot to take out the "debugging" `puts`. Fixed.